# How to take Count of datagridview row

Tags: vb.net, datagrid, count

In my datagridview Gender is the one column in this column Male and Female are two value I want to take total count of Male and Female

Like

```
Gender
======= 
Male
Male
Female
Female
Male
Female
Male
Male
Female
```

I want like this

Here is count of Male=5

And Female=4

Please Help me.

Comment: What is your data source? Why don't you count items at data layer level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Withou a code is hard to help you, but you could try do this by code e.g:

```
ItemSourceDataGrid As ObservableCollection(Of Person)


Dim countMen = 0
Dim countWomen = 0

For Each Person As Person In ItemSourceDataGrid
     If Person.Gender = Male Then
         countMan += 1
     Else
         countWoman += 1
     EndIf
Next
```

You just have to modify to your needs, it is just an idea